# multi-homed systems cross-regional access problem

Tags: database, architecture, microservices

My system consists of 100 microservices, of which there are approximately 10 core microservices. I now want to implement a multi-homed architecture for these 10 core microservices, with one deployment in New York and another in Los Angeles. I also want MySQL to be designed in the same way. However, my concern is that while these core services will access their own data locally via MySQL, the other 90 microservices will require cross-regional access. If there are multiple cross-regional access requests in one transaction, the latency will be very high.

How can I address this architectural limitation?